# Error in parsing the query

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce

I am getting error , whats the problem here?

```
SqlCeCommand com5 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT MAX(OrderID) AS Expr1 FROM Order_Details)", con);
SqlCeDataReader dr5 = com5.ExecuteReader(); // Catches Ex here
while (dr5.Read())
{
     orderID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
}
```

I am using `SQLCe` with `VS2012`, `WPF`, `C#`.

The Exception is

> $exception {"There was an error parsing the query.[ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 62,Token in error = ) ]"}
>        System.Exception {System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException}`

Got the query correct, but these query does not update my database, can you look into it.

```
SqlCeCommand com3 = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Order_Details(Discount, TotalPrice, TotalTax) VALUES(@Discount, @TotalPrice, @TotalTax)", con);
                com3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", discount);
                com3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPrice", gTotal);
                com3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalTax", totalIndividualTax);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra bracket`)` after the `FROM Order_Details` part. Just remove it.

Change it to;

```
SqlCeCommand com5 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT MAX(OrderID) AS Expr1 FROM Order_Details", con);
SqlCeDataReader dr5 = com5.ExecuteReader(); // Catches Ex here
while (dr5.Read())
{
     orderID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
}
```

By the way, I don't understand why you use [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here. Since you just return one row with one column, using [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be better.

For example;

```
SqlCeCommand com5 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT MAX(OrderID) AS Expr1 FROM Order_Details", con);
orderID = (int)com5.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Thanks @Soner, you are right. I am just a copy paste guy. I have alittle knowledge here. And thanks for that extra knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `)` at the end

```
SELECT MAX(OrderID) AS Expr1 FROM Order_Details)
                                               ^--here
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove parenthesis here:

```
SqlCeCommand com5 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT... Order_Details)", con);
                                                             ^
```